# How much distance do I need between quadcopter propellers to avoid issues?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, propeller

For a given propeller size (say 5"), what is the minimum clearance needed between propellers to ensure that not only do they not hit each other (easy to calculate), they also don't interfere too much with each other (i.e. tip vortices, airflow, etc.)

For example consider the following design: an X-shaped quad-copter where the propellers are at the end of each tip of the X - and the X across the diagonal (max distance from the center of the propellers) is 180mm - then 5" propellers will only have .279mm of clearance between them - now assuming that mechanically there are no vibrations/imperfections/etc. that cause them to run into each other, what else is there to avoid in terms of airflow? if they were raised such that two diagonal propellers are lower/higher than the others, would there be any issues? does it depend on the propeller pitch, or if it's a 2-blade or 3-blade propeller?

[image: Propeller Arrangement]

P.S. - I am unsure of the tags, please adjust as necessary

Comment: There are forums like rcgroups specialized in quad-copters (see:   http://www.rcgroups.com/aircraft-electric-multirotors-790 ).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic (and too broad). It belongs to a RC site, as already pointed out.

Comment: @Energizer777 likewise there are also forums specialized in [aviation](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/) - I did also try asking in the [meta](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/are-questions-about-hobby-grade-drones-on-topic-in-general) prior to posting and asking in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24788387#24788387), so if it is indeed off-topic, I think that there is some sort of system flaw here and you should update the [help center](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) accordingly.

Comment: I agree that this would be better answered on a site more devoted to RC. But spacing of full-sized props would be on-topic here, and that is just a matter of scale.

Comment: I think this is a valid question for this site. The fact that another better forum might exist by itself does not seem reason enough to close it on here.

Comment: IANAAE: QC blades spin so fast that I simply cannot fathom any tip vortice issues at all, nor much, if any, interference between the rotor disks.

Comment: Head off to your local hobby/RC store, Best Buy, Walmart, etc and take a look at the commercially produced ones. Seems to me there are some pretty small ones available. Take a tape measure and get some measurements (if they have some out of the box) - that should give you some idea of where to start.

Comment: @FreeMan if all I wanted was measurements, I could just get those from online schematics - somehow as a "new" field, I don't see the local stores having very "well-engineered" designs, rather just "easy to get to work" or stuff from a more retail-oriented perspective (avoid returns) than sound design decisions. They are also horrible as far as which is faster, more agile, efficient, etc. as they will all claim all of those for marketing reasons and not be comparable across models.

Comment: `what else is there to avoid in terms of airflow...`. On-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you gotta keep in mind that the airflow is mainly down, but there will always be a little flow side to side, (thus frames, also used for safer collisions,) so you should put them roughly 1/3 of the diameter of the rotors themselves away from each other. This provides enough space to keep your interference down, as the interference spreads  out to about 1/4 of the radius of the rotor. I have not seen that the number of blades matters much, as long as you follow the 1/3 diameter rule. You want to avoid the counter- airflow that can make your craft less efficient or jack the blades. Note also that raising two of the blades would cause *serious* problems with your efficiency, because two rotors blowing downwards in a cone, unless very effectively controlled, will *kill* the stability, creating unnecessary strain, or in bad cases, frame torque. The two above would create interference for the lower. This could, however, be avoidable if the top two were about 3/4  rotor diameter away, and no higher than 1/4 a rotor diameter. But then you'd be flying a very odd and somewhat unbalanced copter.

Comment: Care to share your calculations (where all those 1/3 and 1/4 comes from), and if you could expand on the "counter-airflow" bit - are you referring to the rotational direction of the blades? (The green ones are indicated as ClockWise, whereas the other two are marked CounterClockWise in my diagram) - anyways, point of different heights was in the case of the propellers otherwise overlapping (or being very close to overlapping and hitting each other if they were on the same plane) - I don't see much benefit if they are already spaced out.

Comment: Would it matter at all if they were shrouded, I.e. there was a wall between the propellers so air could not move diagonally from one to the other?